# MySql show different result to compare to SqLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I try to run same query in mysql and sqlite for the same records.

```
select x, y, d1, d2
from table_name
where (d1 >= $d1 - 0.0000009 and
       d1 <= $d1 + 0.0000009 and
       d2 >= $d2 + 0.0000009 and
       d2 <= $d2 - 0.0000009)
```

but for mysql result is empty and for sqlite is has some value.

$d1 and $d2 is some variable which i fill them during runtime.

I want to know why mysql has not result but sqlite with same query has result?

Comment: What is the datatype of d1 and d2?

Comment: datatype is double

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using between command in sql

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE d1 BETWEEN $d1-0.00000009 AND $d1+0.00000009) as tbl WHERE d2 BETWEEN $d2-0.00000009 AND $d2+0.00000009